# How to correctly comment and uncomment fstab with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I want to use commands to comment and uncomment `swap` partitions in /etc/fstab without side-effects from lines that already are comments.

Use case 1) example fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=97166a83-2932-4a8b-862a-68aa71d4e166 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b95babcf-2d8d-412d-a15d-c8f9de651ee8 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I managed to comment/uncomment it with the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i.bak -r 's/(.+ swap .+)/#\1/' /etc/fstab
sudo sed -i '/^#.* swap /s/^#//' /etc/fstab
```

The problem is that the line `swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation` is also being commented/uncommented and it could cause the document to lose integrity if uncommented twice resulting in:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=97166a83-2932-4a8b-862a-68aa71d4e166 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
 swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b95babcf-2d8d-412d-a15d-c8f9de651ee8 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

UPDATE:

Use case 2) some swap partitions does not have UUID:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=112aa94b-3c82-4a90-9600-e3e45dc820de /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=24ec038a-a164-4d32-809a-5a5552c009e9 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

How could I create a sed expression to make these comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
sudo sed -i 's/.* none.* swap.* sw.*/#&/' /etc/fstab
sudo sed -i '/.* none.* swap.* sw.*/s/^#//' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: @UlLox I am sorry.. your solution works perfectly for the example I posted, but some machines doesn't have UUID in the swap partitions. I have updated the question. Somehow I think it will have to take into account that it is the third parameter <type> = swap.

Comment: Almost perfect.. I saw some in some documentations swap always comes with 'none' mounting point. I think this is enought, no need for the sw. Many examples here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab

Comment: A bonus not to make the comment command recomment a line: `sudo sed -e '/.* none.* swap.*/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/fstab`

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly for me. Having Regex is powerful. I was trying to do for Ubuntu Vagrant machine

Answer (score 1):

put this into a script (or function) and run it with sudo:

```
file="/etc/fstab"; line=$(cat ${file} | grep -nE '^# swap' | cut -d':' -f1); ((line++)); read=$(awk "NR >= ${line} && NR <= ${line}" <<< `cat ${file}`); [ "${read:0:1}" != '#' ] && sed -iE "${line}s:^:# :" "${file}" || sed -iE "${line}s:^#\+ \+::" "${file}"
```